# For i) wouldn't infinity drive the reluctance to approach zero as it is in the demominator? Also wouldn't this result in flux being infinite?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics, electromagnetism

Find the flux density and flux in each of the outer limbs and the central limb of themagnetic circuit shown in Figure 3.2.  Assume relative permeability μr the iron corematerial to be:
(i) infinite ∞;
(ii) 4500

[image]
[image]

Comment: Magnetic material saturates.

Comment: Without an airgap, yes. But the airgap changes things ... a lot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I dont how to go about this question because the reluctance is approaching zero which would make the flux go crazy like infinity. What is even the point for first part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the reluctance of the metal parts was zero, the reluctance of the entire magnetic circuit is dominated by that of the air-gaps.

The point of the exercise is to compare the total reluctance of air-gap + k/infinity, with air-gap + k/4500

Answer (score 1):

> *For i) wouldn't infinity drive the reluctance to approach zero as it
> is in the demominator?*

Your formula here: -

[image]

Appears to be based on this relationship: -

[image]

That formula has nothing that can be driven to infinity; it is just based on material values and dimensions.

> *Also wouldn't this result in flux being infinite?*

If reluctance is zero then flux would be infinite for a non-zero MMF.

Comment: Yes that is the original formula. But why do you add the relative permeability for the second part but not the first by ignoring it. My lecturer said to ignore it but that would mean the flux = infinity.

Comment: @MALLU I haven't ignored anything - mu without a subscript represents mu_0 and mu_R together.